# Set Up for RSpec in a Sinatra modular app

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

This is my first attempt with Sinatra. I built a simple classic app, set up RSpec for it, and got it working. Then, I tried to go modular, in a MVC fashion. Even though the app works in the browser, RSpec throws a `NoMethodError`. I've read Sinatra docs regarding RSpec, also searched a lot here in SO, but I can't find where the bug is. Any clue?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here are my relevant files:

**config.ru**

```
require 'sinatra/base'

Dir.glob('./{app/controllers}/*.rb') { |file| require file }

map('/') { run ApplicationController }
```

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class ZerifApp < Sinatra::Base
  # Only start the server if this file has been
  # executed directly
  run! if __FILE__ == $0
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  set :views, File.expand_path('../../views', __FILE__)
  set :public_dir, File.expand_path('../../../public', __FILE__)

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end
end
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rack/test'

# Also tried this
# Rack::Builder.parse_file(File.expand_path('../../config.ru', __FILE__))

require File.expand_path '../../app.rb', __FILE__

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

module RSpecMixin
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  def app() described_class end
end

RSpec.configure { |c| c.include RSpecMixin }
```

**spec/app_spec.rb**

```
require File.expand_path '../spec_helper.rb', __FILE__

describe "My Sinatra Application" do
  it "should allow accessing the home page" do
    get '/'
    expect(last_response).to be_ok
  end
end
```

**The error**

```
My Sinatra Application should allow accessing the home page
     Failure/Error: get '/'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/app_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you're following [this recipe](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/testing/rspec), correct?

The `described_class` in this line:

```
def app() described_class end
```

is meant to be the class under test, in this case `ZerifApp`. Try it like so:

```
def app() ZerifApp end
```

**EDIT**

It turns out the above answer is not correct about what `described_class` does. I assumed it was a placeholder -- actually it is an RSpec method that returns the class of the implicit subject, that is to say, the thing being tested.

The recipe at the link is misleading because of the way it recommends writing the `describe` block:

```
describe "My Sinatra Application" do
```

This is valid RSpec, but it does not define the subject class. Executing `described_class` in an example for this block will return `nil`. To make it work, replace the describe block:

```
describe ZerifApp do
```

Now `described_class` will return the expected value (`ZerifApp`)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I made such a stupid thing… I really thought that `described_app` was a method. However, this only solved the issue partially. Now instead of a `NoMethodError` I'm getting a 404 (only in RSpec). I'll keep the question still open for today in case somebody else has another answer. Otherwise, I'll check this as the correct answer since it solved the concrete error I was asking about. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

https://pragprog.com/book/7web/seven-web-frameworks-in-seven-weeks

It has some source code to get some ideas from.

This has code example too. https://github.com/laser/sinatra-best-practices